# Copy Specific Indexes of ArrayList to Array

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have an Array List

```
public static List<string> WhatsAppUsers;
```

I want to copy first 20 elements to an array then i want to remove those copied data from array list
I have tried some but they are not working

Tried -

```
WhatsAppUsers.CopyTo(string[] SendingNumbers, 20);
```

Not at all working there is error in this so please if an one have solution without using a for loop

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think he means remove those entries copied to the `string[]` from the `List`. Although he does call it "array list".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the target array properly:

```
string[] SendingNumbers = new string[20]; // Define the array here with a size
WhatsAppUsers.CopyTo(SendingNumbers, 20);
```

Then to remove the first 20 elements, use [List.RemoveRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
WhatsAppUsers.RemoveRange(0, 20);
```

Comment: It will remove index from 0 to 20 means 21 numbers and it will copy only 20 numbers i guess what u think?

Comment: And when coming to this loop again will it copy other 20 numbers?

Comment: As i read it it should take 20 records from index 0. And yes in a loop it will do the first 20 again as they are physically removed from the list

Comment: I think you mean `WhatsAppUsers.CopyTo(0, SendingNumbers, 0, 20);` , `WhatsAppUsers.CopyTo(SendingNumbers, 20);` will copy enire Array to destination starting from index 20.